# How to hook folder to another repository with git

Tags: git, github

I have created GitHub repository X and cloned locally.

Then I created directory A inside this project X by cloning another GitHub repository Y.
Then I changed some files inside folder A in this project X.

Now I want to do add, commit and push this folder A to my GitHub remote of project X.

How do I remove hook to repository Y, and actually add folder A to repository X.

Thank you!

Comment: I would think you can just remove the .git folder from repository Y and then add everything in folder A to repository X as you normally would.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends a bit on what you want to do with this folder `A`. If you only want to have this one version/copy/snapshot of the `A` in your repository, then it’s rather simple. You only need to add the `A` files in the `X` repository and commit them. You can even remove the `/A/.git` folder to make the `A` subdirectory no longer a Git repository on its own.

If you want to preserve the history of `A` and want to keep it separate enough so you can, for example, make changes to `A` and save those to it, instead of keeping the changes only in the parent repository `X`, then you should look into [submodules](http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules). They allow you to reference another repository `A` as a submodule within your existing repository `X`. So you link `A` into `X` but still keep `A` separate on its own.

Comment: I actually ended up deleting /A/.git folder. Initially I was refusing to do that because I thought git manages .git folder in each subdirectory of /A/ and I was too lazy to remove each. However only /A/.git/ folder was removed, and then I did standard "git add; git commit; git push;" procedure

Comment: Yeah, Git only has a single `.git` folder at the root of your working directory. It keeps things simple ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can use submodules or subtree.
They are more or less the same.

Read **[here](http://blogs.atlassian.com/2013/05/alternatives-to-git-submodule-git-subtree/)** to find out the differences between the 2.

The main idea is that you manage an inner folder as a "standalone" (repository or subtree)